# Prove that any non negative number has a square root

Tags: real-analysis, radicals

I am in a real analysis class and am having difficulty with this problem:

> prove that any non negative real number has a square root.

Comment: The square function is a bijection on the positive reals (because it is continuous and strictly increasing).

Comment: why the downvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $b>0$ and consider the set given by: $$S_b=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x^2<b\}.$$ Then prove that this set has an upper bound, and that $\alpha=\sup S_b$ satisfies $\alpha^2=b$